# MS SQL ODBC Connection with NO Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp-classic, odbc

I'm trying to connect to MS SQL using ODBC but keep getting the 
"Login failed for user 'User-PC\User'" error.

```
web.config 
<add name="SQLDbConnection" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1; Database=HMS; Integrated Security=false; User Id=sa; password=root" providerName="System.Data.Odbc "/>

C#
        string query = "...";
        OdbcConnection msSQLConnection = new OdbcConnection(strConnection);
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, msSQLConnection);
        command.Connection.Open();
```

I tried using the below and it's ok. Any idea how I can get ODBC to work?

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDbConnection"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COMPANY_ID from COMPANY", cn);
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            rdr.Read();
        }
```

Comment: what error did u got ?

Comment: Login failed for user 'User-PC\User

Comment: I tried using SqlCommand to login and it's fine. I'm pretty sure it's due to windows authentication. Any idea how I can turn it off?

Comment: Why are you using the sa account to connect to anything???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Connection and ODBC Connection do not use the same connection strings. For the ODBC connection you need to specify the driver.

For SQL Server 2012:

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=HMS;Uid=sa;Pwd=root;
```

Comment: I tried using DRIVER={SQL Native Client};" + ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDbConnection"].ToString(); Got the error "Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection."

Comment: Please connect the SQL Server Profiler and monitor the Audit Login and Audit Login Failed events in the Security category. Check to see what are the credentials that appear for the login attempt.

Comment: Also make sure you are using "SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode" under Server Authentication

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this :

```
    DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=127.0.0.1; DATABASE=HMS; USER=sa; PASSWORD=root;
```

Then take a look in here :[OBDC example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/odbcconnection)
and then in here : [Connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Comment: I'm getting the error Login Failed for User; Reason: Not Associated with a Trusted SQL Server Connection. Server mode is mixed authentication.

Comment: It seems that it's using the iis user to connect to that db

Comment: which connection string did u used?